# Google Calendar API: Event source.title and source.url : new calendar interface shows "This event was automatically created from an email."

Tags: google-calendar-api

When creating an event with the API:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

If I fill the fields source.title and source.url:

> source.title     string     Title of the source; for example a title of a web page or an email subject.
>   source.url     string     URL of the source pointing to a resource. The URL scheme must be HTTP or HTTPS.

With the old interface, on the event I could see a read-only field, between "Calendar" and "Description":

> Source   [Link icon] The title of my link, from [source.title]

And "The title of my link, from [source.title]" was a link to [source.url]

[image: Old UI]

With the new calendar interface, the same event instead shows:

> [Email icon] This event was automatically created from an email. [View confirmation]

And [View confirmation] is a link to [source.url]

[image: New UI]

Am I missing something? Is that a bug on the new interface or is the API documentation deprecated for these fields?

The bug tracker link to that issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73334552

Comment: Wandering the same thing. Perhaps Google didn't update it yet.

Comment: @Tool and no answer there either: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-calendar-api/0rPDEd98ZOU . I did report that bug to Google using the "Send feedback" feature both in the new google calendar UI and in the documentation page.

Comment: Thanks - please leave an answer here if you get feedback from them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was recently a large upgrade of the Google calendar web UI.  This happend around October if memory servies.

This looks like a bug to me there have been a few of them asssoicated with the API and the new web UI not being updated and fully tested.

I am going to reach out to my contacts at Google to have someone check this in the mean time would you mind posting this on the issue tracker and pasting me the link?  [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%2B)

Comment: I sent them your issue tracker link I will let you know if I hear anything.